# iSCSI shared disks with custom device name on clients

Tags: linux, redhat, storage, iscsi, kernel

I'm using RHEL 7.9 (Maipo) and need to setup for all iSCSI clients the same device name, like /dev/sdb or /dev/thiscustomname.

I could do that by sharing the source disk using multipath, but for Db2 pureScale it cannot be a a symlink. This is how it is showing in the clients A and B:

```
Client A:

/dev/sdb                  mpath_me
└─/dev/mapper/db2data
/dev/sdc                  mpath_me
└─/dev/mapper/db2tieb

Client B (has 2 more disks than Client A):

/dev/sdd                  mpath_me
└─/dev/mapper/db2data
/dev/sde                  mpath_me
└─/dev/mapper/db2tieb
```

For Db2 purScale, when I issue an instance creation with the command:

```
/opt/ibm/db2/V115fp8ps/instance/db2icrt \
    -m  n1.local -mnet  n1  \
    -cf c1.local -cfnet c1  \
    -instance_shared_dev  /dev/mapper/db2data          \
    -tbdev                /dev/mapper/db2tieb          \
    -u  db2fenc1   db2inst1
```

The error is

```
DBI20013E  The database product installer detected that the given device path
"/dev/mapper/db2data" is a symbolic link on the host "c1.local".
```

Db2 pureScale instance creation complains about symlinks, so I cannot use any other entries in /dev/disk, because they're all symlinks and throws the same error:

```
/dev/disk/by-id
/dev/disk/by-label
/dev/disk/by-partlabel
/dev/disk/by-partuuid
/dev/disk/by-path
/dev/disk/by-uuid
```

That's the reason I need to use a device name (not a mapper name/symlink).

Is it possible that all clients have the same device name for these iSCSI remote disks, and, sure, ones that I can set myself like **/dev/sfa** or something way distant from the disks that kernel set for local disks (sda, sdb, sdc, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names you're trying to have fixed are not supposed to persist in any modern Linux environment. Instead of trying to fix them, you should consider using any of `/dev/disk/by-label`, `/dev/disk/by-uuid`, `/dev/disk/by-id` or `/dev/disk/by-path`, depending on what kind of SAN you're using to back this storage.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but you didn't pay attention to what I said: all entries under by-id, by-label, by-partlabel, by-partuuid, by-path and by-uuid are symlinks to the original devices (/dev/sda, /dev/sdb and so on). 
Db2 pureScale do not allow to create a instance because it reads them as symlinks and abort the installation. The error it throws is: "DBI20013E  The database product installer detected that the given device path "/dev/mapper/db2data" is a symbolic link on the host "c1.local"."  - The same occurs for any entry under /dev/disk/* .

Comment: Based on your answer I updated my question to be more clear on the purpose. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I got your point, IBM still has its own way of doing things :). Based on that, the simplest solution would be to get real device name upon startup (I assume you're wrapping all this in systemd service or a script of some kind anyway) with something like `realdev=\`readlink -f /dev/mapper/db2data\`` and then reference `$realdev` in your instance launch command instead of device name.

Comment: To be honest the answer of the question of this post is this. No doubt. But the problem I described really doesn't exists. For the ones seeking knowledge on Db2 pureScale, please read my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I was looking into the wrong documentation and the wrong virtualization options. IBM Db2 pureScale feature uses WWN number (shown in `lsblk -a -o WWN` command). So it really doesn't matter if iSCSI disks are getting the same device name/number as in /dev/sda or /dev/sdb.

Another error was on the VMWare Workstation Pro 16/17 virtualization, which by default don't allow disks to have consistent UUID thus giving the same WWN number all over the VMs. To fix that, shutdown the VM and add this line in the main VM file (the one with .vmx extension):

```
disk.enableuuid = "TRUE"
```

Save the file and then restart the VM.

As I created all disks from scratch for each VM, that solved my problem. If you have cloned your VMs and disks, you'll need to find VMWare support to change disk UUID.

So the original problem of this question... is not really a problem.